# Why is the Visual Studio runtime library source code stored in two directories?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

There seem to be two paths containing Microsoft Visual Studio runtime source files:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\crt\src

and

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include

Some files appear in both directories, but have different sizes. I looked at one file in particular and it had the same method defined in both files.

So my question is, what is the difference in usage for the two paths? I would like to know when I am debugging (I dont mean debug mode) in Visual Studio, which file is the code on the screen?

Comment: I think you don't have "Show file extensions" enabled in Explorer so are confusing Header and Source files.

Comment: The files I was looking at were both header files because the use of templates means the implementation must be in a header file. They both contained implementation for the same method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The CRT sits at the bottom of the Visual C++ libraries stack: the rest of the libraries depend on it and practically all native modules depend on it as well. It contains two kinds of stuff: (1) the C Standard Library and various extensions, and (2) runtime functionality required for things like process startup and exception handling. Because the CRT sits at the bottom of the stack, it is the logical place to start the process of stabilizing the libraries.

---

From [The Great C Runtime (CRT) Refactoring by James McNellis](https://web.archive.org/web/20160113143736/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/10/the-great-crt-refactoring.aspx):

(1) We ship most of the sources for the CRT with Visual Studio; you can find them in the Visual Studio installation directory under `VC\crt\src`.

(2) In Visual Studio 2013 there are 6,830 `#if`, `#ifdef`, `#ifndef`, `#elif`, and `#else` directives in the sources that we ship with the product; in the Visual Studio "14" CTP there are 1,656. These numbers do not include directives in headers and they do include the STL source files which are largely untouched by this refactoring effort, so this isn't a perfect measurement, but it's indicative of the amount of cleanup that's been done.

Comment: I doubt you're James McNellis in disguise, so you should provide *proper attribution* (at a minimum, his name and a link to [the original article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/06/10/the-great-crt-refactoring.aspx) you're quoting). I also do not see how this answers the question.

Comment: @angel Which one does VS use when I am stepping through code?

Comment: in crt path of course, it's more complete.
normaly, in crt path you have more files....

Comment: As I understand, one folder is for runtime and the other for compliation....
the editing could generate problem (if a function is missing) that why, I think windows don't want that file are editable...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Nope. James McNellis doesn't wear a disguise. :-)

Comment: With Windows 10 and Visual Studio 2015 and up, some of the source has moved into \Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits, out of the Visual Studio CRT\src directories.

Comment: You aren’t shipping CRT source. You only ship source for a couple of trivial functions like memcpy. Everything else is closed source, e.g. try to find `powf.asm` source file.

Answer (score 13):

The `include` directory has all of the public headers.  These are headers that you can include in your code, like `<stdio.h>` and `<type_traits>`, plus implementation headers required by those headers.

The `crt\src` directory contains the CRT sources, including most of the `.asm`, `.c`, and `.cpp` files used to build the CRT.  This directory also has a copy of many of the CRT headers, and in some cases these headers are different from what are in the `include` directory.  This is purely an artifact of how the CRT was built.

When debugging into inline code defined in the CRT headers, the debugger should always pick the right header.  If both directories contain the same copy of a header, then the debugger will just pick one and since the headers are the same it doesn't matter which one it picks.  If the headers are different, then which header the debugger picks depends on the object into which the inline function was compiled.  If the object is part of the CRT, you'll step into the header from `crt\src`; if the object is from one of your source files, you'll step into the header from `include`.  Basically, the debugger should always be able to find the correct copy of the header.

We've greatly simplified this in the Visual Studio "14" CTP.  There are no longer any public headers in the `crt\src` directory, and the headers that are shipped in the `include` directory are the same ones that were used to build the CRT.